# FFmpeg generates different number of frame for ORIGINAL and CONVERTED files even though they have same duration and frame rate

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediacodec

I have two files with the following configuration. I am extracting frames using FFmpeg and then encoding the frames with `MediaCodec` using the frame duration to calculate timestamp in android.

While processing the first file, FFmpeg generates around **`3000`** plus frames but for the second file, FFmpeg generates only around **`1500`** frames.

As I am using the frame duration to encode video, the output video duration changes for the above case. What is it that I am doing wrong? And Why FFmpeg generates a different number of frames?

[**VID-20210223-WA0009.mp4**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tfaPBzUArFWT-YjGh8Xh_TXwShNsOynt/view?usp=sharing)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID-20210223-WA0009.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
  Duration: 00:00:50.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1410 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 480x848, 1345 kb/s, 59.96 fps, 59.94 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
At least one output file must be specified
```

> - [Frame pts and duration](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/JVHCgDTjrW/)

[**VID-20210223-WA0009_1.mp4**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSJqRQrJHpNH9xCkf57y7xB1sjoq7PJS/view?usp=sharing)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID-20210223-WA0009_1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.48.100
  Duration: 00:00:50.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1376 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 480x848, 1301 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 119.88 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

> - [Frame Pts and duration](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jW6WtFgKYW/)
> - Converted from the first file using FFmpeg.

Comment: What was your conversion command?

Comment: @Gyan I'm not using FFmpeg command. I am using a `.c` file that extracts frames from a file and then using OpenGL to update the frame and then saving the updated frame using android MediaCodec.

Comment: *Converted from the first file using FFmpeg.* --> how did you do this?

Comment: @Gyan First file was converted using the following FFmpeg command. 

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i VID-20210223-WA0009.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec h264 -profile:v main -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -color_range 2 -preset superfast -vsync 1 -acodec copy VID-20210223-WA0009_1.mp4`